# Vue js mounted scroll to specific div

Tags: vuejs2

I found this script and works fine when you click on the button. What i want to achieve is when the page load it automatic scrolls to that specific div.

How can i achieve that?

```
<button id="goto" @click="goto('porto')">Go to porto</button>

<div class="page" ref="porto">
    Porto page
</div>

methods: {
    goto(refName) {
        var element = this.$refs[refName];
        console.log(element);
        var top = element.offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, top);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the lifecycle hooks in Vue

so something like a mounted hook:

```
mounted:{
  this.goto('porto')
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**mounted** is called **after render**, however if we try to scroll immediately on mount,
scroll might not work.

a simple **setTimeout** without a timeout does the trick, this might look ugly, but works like a charm.

```
mounted() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  scrollToDiv();
 })
}
```

Comment: I was struggling for a day to figure it out, this has completely helped me.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: this helped me get unstuck too. curious if anyone knows why this works. is there a better lifecycle event to use or is this a quirk of Vue?

Answer (score 0):

I such a case I'm always using the nextTick method.

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue';
```

In your mounted method you would simply call:

```
mounted() {
    nextTick(() => this.goto('porto'));
},
```